# Write a program to prevent an automatic computer restart

Tags: c#

I sometimes run processes overnight and sometimes they are cut off by automatic restarts by my IT department.  Is it possible to write a C# program that will prevent this from happening?

Comment: How about talking to your IT department?

Comment: Question title reads like a homework assignment.

Comment: I doubt you will have the administrative rights to overwrite them. If they are offline processes though you could simply try to disable the network connection.

Comment: Yeah, it goes like this: Ethernet.Cable.Unplug().

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form". None of this is true

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Well, this is a problem that shouldn't be solved by a programming solution so it's not really suited to Stack Overflow.  Maybe it should have been closed as "off topic" instead.  Although it's kind of "inadvertently off-topic" (if that's a thing), since the OP was asking for a programming solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your IT department is using SMS/SCCM, WSUS, or Group Policy to make updates, then install updates and reboot your machine there is no way to prevent them, as they are using a DOMAIN SYSTEM Account, and chances are your account is only a local administrator and not domain administrator. You can ask them to remove your WORKSTATION from their Group Policy, or place you in a different Organiational Unit in Active Directory to prevent this. You can also schedule your scripts to run outside of their maintenance window as well to prevent conflict.

However keep in mind that most of the updates they push are critical to preventing security vulnerabilities on your machine or maintain the integrity of the network and domain in some way. A network is only as strong as the weakest link. blah blah blah. ;)